# How do I show all products from a specific category in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I want to show all products from a specific ccategory in Prestashop tpl file.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

By default the prestashop has this category page that displays the products of that category.
It is like yourshop.com/index.php?controller=category&id_category=*CAT-ID*